# Was bedeutet "wär von Vorteil"?

Tags: expression

Ich habe diesen Kommentar ein paar Mal gesehen:

> Wär von Vorteil.

Was bedeutet er?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die Bedeutung der Redewendung, die v. a. umgangssprachlich verwendet wird, hängt etwas vom Kontext ab. Grundsätzlich heißt es: **kein "muss", aber nützlich und gerne gesehen**. Hier einige Anwendungsfälle, um die Bedeutung besser zu vermitteln:

> "Möchten Sie, dass ich Ihnen die drei Stück Pizza einpacke?"
>   "Wär von Vorteil."

Im Sinne: danke für den Hinweis, muss nicht unbedingt sein, aber ich nutze Ihr Angebot gerne.

> "Soll ich den Projektplan heute noch fertigstellen?"
>   "Wär von Vorteil."

Hier will der Antwortende ausdrücken, dass er gerne hätte, dass die Arbeit noch im Laufe des Tages erledigt würde. Aber er will es nicht ausdrücklich befehlen.

Dabei ist situationsbezogen sehr stark zu achten, dass die Antwort nicht hämisch wirkt, wenn man nur höflich sein möchte. Hier spielt auch die Art wie man den Satz sagt eine große Rolle. Es besteht immer die Gefahr missverstanden zu werden. Wie tohuwawohu im Kommentar zu dieser Antwort schreibt, empfiehlt es sich eine alternative Antwort zu wählen, wenn man sicher sein möchte, richtig verstanden zu werden.

Im letzten Beispiel mit einem ironischen/sarkastischen Unterton, um im Gegensatz zu den beiden vorigen Dialogen auszudrücken, dass der Sachverhalt *sehr wichtig* ist:

> "Die Bremsen sollten nun wieder funktionieren."
>   "Wär von Vorteil."

Comment: Geschrieben wäre es von Vorteil, "Das wäre von Vorteil" zu verwenden.

Comment: @splattne - wäre ich in den Beispielen der Fragesteller, dann würde ich nach der Antwort „Wär von Vorteil“ davon ausgehen, dass ich eigentlich besser nicht gefragt, sondern gleich gehandelt hätte (siehe meine Deutung der Phrase). Das ist aber wohl sehr stark von der Situation abhängig. Auf einen nützlichen / entgegenkommenden Vorschlag würde ich eher eine klare, freundliche Rückmeldung erwarten: „Das wäre sehr freundlich“ / „Das wäre prima“. Das kann man zwar auch sarkastisch einsetzen, aber „wäre von Vorteil“ ist mir etwas zu diffus, um wirklich freundlich zu sein.

Comment: @tohuwawohu ja, diesen Aspekt finde ich auch wichtig. Deshalb gab's auch ein +1 für deine Antwort. Ich werde noch einen Satz hinzufügen.

Comment: @bernd_k: Wär von Vorteil!

Comment: @tohuwawohu: Ich würde sagen, es hängt sehr davon ab, ob man gleichberechtigter Partner oder Boss ist - dann ist die Phrase als Wunsch zu verstehen - oder Angestellter, Arbeiter, abhängig Beschäftigter oder Schüler/Azubi ist, dann ist der Wunsch wohl eher als Anordnung zu verstehen.

Comment: P.S.: Es gibt auch noch den Fall, wo man gemeinsam aus dem Fenster schaut, und einer sagt: "Wär schön, es hörte auf zu regnen". "Wäre von Vorteil." ist dann nur eine Zustimmung, wenn auch ein "Es " davor nicht schadete.

Answer (score 5):

M.E. handelt es sich oft um eine Zustimmung/Aufforderung in ironischer oder sarkastischer Form: der Konjunktiv II drückt eigentlich „bloß“ eine Möglichkeit aus, ohne aufdringlich wirken zu wollen; gemeint ist aber häufig das Gegenteil: Der Aussage wird **unbedingt** zugestimmt, sie sollte sofort umgesetzt werden. Beispiel:

> A: „Mist - vor einer halben Stunde habe ich die Hauptwasserleitung angebohrt, und es kommt immer noch Wasser nach. Ich glaube, ich sollte mal nach dem Absperrventil sehen.“
>
> B: „Wäre von Vorteil...“

Die Aussage kann natürlich auch wörtlich gemeint sein, aber spontan - ohne nähere Informationen - verbinde ich damit eher Ironie bzw. Sarkasmus.